# CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context while editing an existing and working code file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I need assistance with my ASP.Net MVC project. This project is running well but when I try to make some changes I get this error

> CS0103    The name '**ASPxDocumentViewer1**' does not exist in the current
>   context **2_Reporting_FinIncomeStatement.aspx**, BrokerOffice

I have 3 files that I am working on

```
FinIncomeStatement.aspx
FinIncomeStatement.aspx.cs
FinIncomeStatement.aspx.designer.cs
```

---

**Sample Code**

> In the FinIncomeStatement.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FinIncomeStatement.aspx.cs" Inherits="BrokerOffice.Reporting.FinIncomeStatement" %>


<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v15.2.Web, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 10%; background: white" class="form-horizontal">

    </div>
    <dx:ASPxDocumentViewer ID="ASPxDocumentViewer1" runat="server" ReportTypeName="BrokerOffice.Reporting.XtraFinIncomeStatement" Theme="Moderno"></dx:ASPxDocumentViewer>
</asp:Content>
```

> In the FinIncomeStatement.aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BrokerOffice.Reporting
{
    public partial class FinIncomeStatement : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

              XtraFinIncomeStatement report = new XtraFinIncomeStatement();


               ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = report;
        }

    }
}
```

> In the FinIncomeStatement.aspx.designer.cs file

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace BrokerOffice.Reporting {


    public partial class FinIncomeStatement {

        /// <summary>
        /// ASPxDocumentViewer1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ASPxDocumentViewer ASPxDocumentViewer1;
    }
}
```

Now ***I do not*** have this file **`2_Reporting_FinIncomeStatement.aspx`** in my folder explorer. **Where is VS getting that from?**

1. I have restarted my computer several times
2. Deleted the .vs and .git files from my project
3. Cleaned the project and rebuilt the project
4. Renamed CodeBehind to CodeFile in my .aspx form and back as well
5. Opened the project with vs2019 and vs2015

If I remove the file completely and add a new form then copy and paste the same code it works.

But I can't keep on deleting files and add new files whenever I want to add or edit some code.
My question is what could be the cause of the additional **`2_Reporting_FinIncomeStatement.aspx`** mystery form. If I search the entire solution I cant find it but I can find it labeled here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part of your aspx file.

```
Inherits="BrokerOffice.Reporting.FinIncomeStatement"
```

Because your are not Inheriting nothing on this page.